# Wipe out EB init config

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to wipe out a previous 'eb init' config? The previous config has resources that are non-existent on an earlier AWS account. I am using a new AWS account and want to initialize an existent Beanstalk environment.

Thanks..

Answer (score 26):

You can always add `--help` to a command to see the options available to you. Eg. `eb init --help`. This reveals that you can use the `-i` switch to force interactive mode. This will force a re-asking of all the EB options.

So just type `eb init -i` an you're done!

Answer (score 16):

Go to the directory of your project (the directory where you originally ran the "eb init" command).  Delete the .elasticbeanstalk directory.  You can now run "eb init" again, and it will prompt you for your configuration information.

Comment: Good answer--this command option repeats the configuration selection process (if you want to deploy to a different region, for example). [This shouldn't have been downvoted, but that's true site-wide now.]